# print chart isn't working for columnrange HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

[image]

error thrown by highchart-more library while clicking on print chart (exporting button).
i'm trying to export (print chart) a columnrange graph.
Even i found that the demo example on highchart is also throwing the same error.
    [https://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange?**cf_chl_jschl_tk**=75ef57b90426bb8711968566eb4df741cf64c9a6-1591202845-0-AZwTKQgqzxGQZDW-Rq4JOgEgcwcOmwgfRMadAmbWU1-gwfLNp3h-bTchWfh2zFIRQTkOHFAlxZTshcL9Zn5dvQqDHGY7VRsSpCOoL-tzk-fkIW2gwOt7DrGyZSWjuljLg-CvjjO2Z87if54GYlLmpeVuDHpL-5Vfl0mleCW0U8WdHUjmRyswY_332RrXJxtjoJhCBqY0AYpW9NnDXfK7Kl6dRkat5Roeeso4bEjY2hkWnylV7Eo0K7BxzEBPDAXQZZLionI8SGtXNon3v12b3MBE_TwsReW9JfaECbtlnzDmWnq4PA1G8u_hWU7B8pYEx9LQ9r40INKMVf1Jdkcsf_H6CMmZ6C211e9cvI06KHhP](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=75ef57b90426bb8711968566eb4df741cf64c9a6-1591202845-0-AZwTKQgqzxGQZDW-Rq4JOgEgcwcOmwgfRMadAmbWU1-gwfLNp3h-bTchWfh2zFIRQTkOHFAlxZTshcL9Zn5dvQqDHGY7VRsSpCOoL-tzk-fkIW2gwOt7DrGyZSWjuljLg-CvjjO2Z87if54GYlLmpeVuDHpL-5Vfl0mleCW0U8WdHUjmRyswY_332RrXJxtjoJhCBqY0AYpW9NnDXfK7Kl6dRkat5Roeeso4bEjY2hkWnylV7Eo0K7BxzEBPDAXQZZLionI8SGtXNon3v12b3MBE_TwsReW9JfaECbtlnzDmWnq4PA1G8u_hWU7B8pYEx9LQ9r40INKMVf1Jdkcsf_H6CMmZ6C211e9cvI06KHhP)

Answer (score 1):

This is a Highcharts bug that is reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13575

The issue is resolved and the fix will applied in the next version. As a workaround you can use the code from master or some previous version:

```
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.0.4/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.0.4/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.0.4/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/5019/

**Highcharts file service:** https://code.highcharts.com/

Comment: Now the columnrange graph graph is throwing error for missing module even above specific version is added to code.

pointing out to latest version is fixing everything from now.

Comment: Hi @Prashant, The example that I provided still works correctly. Could you reproduce the problem?

Comment: i just check thoroughly . i only replaced  
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.0.4/highcharts-more.js"></script>
while other highcharts library was the updated/latest one. 

the above combination of highcharts libraries work well.